# Selenium Webdriver Node.js : How to load and execute jQuery code

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm using **Selenium webdriver & Node.JS** for functional testing.

i'm trying to use **jquery** code to do some treatment.

1. First of all , i tried to include jquery and load it within :

   driver.executeScript("var s=window.document.createElement('script');\
                 s.src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js';\
                 window.document.head.appendChild(s);");

-> *this treatment seems to be executed (since i'm not catching a related error)*

2. But when trying to use jquery functionalities , here is an example :

   driver.executeScript("$('#edit-submit').on('click',function(){alert('test');})");

   i'm catching this :

> My error handler... WebDriverError: unknown error: $ is not a function

it seems that jquery is either not successfully loaded or i'm not using it properly.

**Suggestions ?**